# Error in python web scraper wont run properly

Tags: python, web

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20cards'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each product
containers =  page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item-container"})

for container in containers:
    brand = container[0].img["title"].title()

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].txt


    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()


    print("Brand: "+ brand)
    print("product name: "+ product_name)
    print("shipping: "+ shipping)
```

After I run this program it gives me the following errors.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "my_first_websraper.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       brand = container[0].img["title"].title()   File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py",
>   line 1368, in **getitem**
>       return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 0

When he runs it in the tutorial it not only lists everything properly but it lists everything on the website the same way. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

For an idea of how it should look got to 28:55 on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't using same packages or even close to the same code as you but I was able to get each item and its price using selenium! I've had issues with other libraries because they just get the html content and cant do headless browsers (generally). This causes issues with rendered web pages because they get the page before all the products are rendered.

I got the prices on the page with this selenium script:

EDIT: added sorting

EDIT: added excel output and formatting of numbers

```
url = "https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20cards"

driver.get(url)

# let the page load
time.sleep(5)

get_price = lambda x: x.text.split(' ')[0].replace('$', '').replace('Free', '0')

# get all the prices of the products on the page
prices = [{'product': item.find_element_by_class_name('item-title').text,
           'price': get_price(item.find_element_by_class_name('price-current')),
           'shipping': get_price(item.find_element_by_class_name('price-ship'))}
          for item in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item-info')]

prices_sorted = sorted(prices, key=lambda x: x['price'])

# prettify the output with json
import json
print(json.dumps(prices_sorted, indent=4))


# -------------- export to excel --------------
from openpyxl import Workbook

 # create the workbook
wb = Workbook()

# select the first sheet
ws = wb.active
# write the header row
ws.append([key for key in prices_sorted[0].keys()])
for row in prices_sorted:
    # write each row
    ws.append([value for value in row.values()])

path = './prices.xlsx'
# save the file
wb.save(filename = path)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "product": "GIGABYTE Radeon RX 570 DirectX 12 GV-RX570GAMING-4GD REV2.0 Video Card",
        "price": "$119.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "ASRock Phantom Gaming D Radeon RX 570 DirectX 12 RX570 4G Video Card",
        "price": "$119.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "MSI Radeon RX 570 DirectX 12 RX 570 8GT OC Video Card",
        "price": "$135.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "XFX Radeon RX 580 DirectX 12 RX-580P8RFD6 Video Card",
        "price": "$189.99",
        "shipping": "$5.99"
    },
    {
        "product": "MSI GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER DirectX 12 GTX 1660 SUPER VENTUS XS OC Video Card",
        "price": "$249.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "SAPPHIRE PULSE Radeon RX 5600 XT DirectX 12 100419P6GL Video Card",
        "price": "$289.99",
        "shipping": "$3.99"
    },
    {
        "product": "EVGA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti SC ULTRA GAMING, 06G-P4-1667-KR, 6GB GDDR6, Dual Fan, Metal Backplate",
        "price": "$299.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "EVGA GeForce RTX 2060 KO ULTRA GAMING Video Card, 06G-P4-2068-KR, 6GB GDDR6, Dual Fans, Metal Backplate",
        "price": "$319.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "MSI GeForce RTX 2060 DirectX 12 RTX 2060 VENTUS XS 6G OC Video Card",
        "price": "$339.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "ASUS GeForce RTX 2060 Overclocked 6G GDDR6 Dual-Fan EVO Edition Graphics Card (DUAL-RTX2060-O6G-EVO)",
        "price": "$349.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "ASUS ROG Strix Radeon RX 5700 XT ROG-STRIX-RX5700XT-O8G-GAMING Video Card",
        "price": "$459.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    },
    {
        "product": "GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 2070 Super WINDFORCE OC 3X 8G Graphics Card, GV-N207SWF3OC-8GD",
        "price": "$499.99",
        "shipping": "Free"
    }
]
```

Excel output:

[image]

Here is a link to the Colab sheet so you can run it yourself: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LLTyZ0ATiUS3f-WJdGvnlaUXv0h8U4i-

Comment: is there a way to organize the Json file so that it organizes it by best deal?

Comment: of course! see the added line: `prices_sorted = sorted(prices, key=lambda x: x['price'])` and if this is what you're after, please mark as the solution

Comment: 2 last thing is there a way can make it a spreadsheet instead of JSON? Also is there a way to incorporate customer reviews from the website?

Comment: I added export to excel but it is also possible to do csv

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down on the YouTube video to the top comment, the author explains the issue.

It doesn't look like `container.div` will give you the div from the `item-info` class, but rather the div from the `item-badges` class. This is because the latter occurs before the former. When you access any tag with the dot(`.`) operator, it will just return the first instance of that tag, as is the case here.

To solve this, use the `find()` method to find the exact div which contains the information that you want.

example: `divWithInfo = containers[0].find("div", "item-info")`

Comment: how would I adjust it for the other information? also, how would I get it to print every item on the page? not just the first.

Comment: As far as implementation, replacing  ` brand = container[0].img["title"].title()` with an edited version of the example would work.

Comment: And for every item, just follow the same syntax as the answer, but replacing it with your variables, attributes, etc.

Comment: so it should look like this:

 brand = container[0].img["title"].title()

 title_container = container.find("a", {"class":"item-title"})
 product_name = title_container[0].txt


 shipping_container = container.find("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
 shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213265/discussion-between-sean-blumenfeld-and-conflagrate).